# C# How to get field's properties (Field type, default value, formula, ..) in Lotus Notes using Interop.Domino.dll

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I'm working with Lotus Notes `using Interop.Domino.dll` library, but I don't know how to get field's properties (including field type, default value, ...).

Answer (score 2):

There is a [NotesForm](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESFORM_CLASS.html) class, and you can get the names of fields from that, but there is no class available to represent a field and its attributes. You'll have to use the [NotesDXLExporter](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDXLEXPORTER_CLASS.html) class to get an XML representation of the form and parse the XML to get the field properties.

And you're probably better off going with DXL for any information you need about design elements, anyhow, because there are known problems with the interop classes that represent collections of deisgn elements when running on 64 bit Windows - which is not officially supported by IBM.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard already mentioned. Use the DXLExporter

```
var exporter = lnSession.CreateDXLExporter();
exporter.OutputDOCTYPE = false; //shortens the XML a bit
```

and then export the NotesDocument to an XML-Representation.

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
String s = exporter.Export(notesDocument);

//remove the namespace for easier XPATH
s = s.Replace(" xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl'", ""); 
xml.LoadXml(s);
```

In the XML, there are the notes items f.e.:

```
<item name='$CSVersion'><text>2</text></item>
<item name='StartDate'><datetime>20160323</datetime></item>
```

as you can see, there is at least a basic type information in there to work with.

If you have the names and types sorted out, you may get the item with

```
notesDocument.GetFirstItem(itemName); //return NotesItem
```

or the value directly with

```
notesDocument.GetItemValue(itemName);
```

which will return an Object, which you can cast afterwards to the desired type.